# Missing language on physical keyboard options

Tags: languages, external-keyboard

Mongolian language doesn't exist in the physical keyboard section. Is there any way to install an additional language on an Android tablet?

Comment: tried gboard, swiftkey. and tried to contact google. Found no way

Answer (score 0):

Install following [Extra Keyboard Layout](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=varzan.extraKeyboardLayouts&hl=en_US) from Play Store

It includes among many, Mongolian Keyboard Layout for Physical Keyboard use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to switch (**not** <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> this only changes layout for on screen keyboard)